# Java error while loading files in sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I am working on Spark with R by using "sparklyr" package.

Following error is coming when loading files in sparklyr:

My code is:

```
library(sparklyr)

sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", version = "2.0.1")

iris_tbl <- copy_to(sc, iris)
```

Error showed:

```
Error: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:258)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:359)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSharedState.metadataHive$lzycompute(HiveSharedState.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSharedState.metadataHive(HiveSharedState.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(HiveSharedState.scala:46)
```

I have tried to find/research the solution but havn't find a confirm solution on any of other websites.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error in a Cloudera Cluster from the edge node. It seems to be some capacity issue somewhere I am still not clear. 
The following mods make your code work

```
config <- spark_config()
config$spark.yarn.keytab <- "<user.keytab>"
config$spark.yarn.principal <- "<user@host>"
config$spark.executor.cores <- 4
config$spark.executor.memory <- "20g"
config$spark.driver.memory <- "40g"
config$spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead <- "8g"
config$spark.yarn.executors.memoryOverhead <- "8g"
config$spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max <- "256m"
config$spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled <- "false"
config$spark.executor.instances <- 24
config$sparklyr.cores.local <- 4
sc <- spark_connect(master = "yarn-client", version = "1.6.0", config = config) 


iris_tbl <- copy_to(sc, iris)
```

Hope this helps.... 
however, I am still having problems with large Hive tables not loading if I run

```
dbGetQuery(sc, 'select * from large_table limit 10')
```

Comment: All those settings are not necessary when your running a local cluster. Your answer is not a work around since he is trying with spark 2.0.1 and your loading it with 1.6.0.